# How I open an Instagram page inside my app with a webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, instagram

I try to open an Instagram page (hashtags page) inside my app using WebView but it doesn’t work, and I don't know why. It’s an important part for my app, can you help me, this is the code I use:

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/instaWebView"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="385dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/instaTV"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

---

```
instaWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.instaWebView);
            instaWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
            instaWebView.loadUrl(
"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags//?hl=en");
```

my code appears like that :

[image]

Comment: please don't paste links to images with code - copy and paste it here!!!

Comment: To be specific, don't add images with the *result* of your code without backing it up with the actual code used to create it. Create a [mcve]

Comment: I might be late but the url u r trying to load is not valid. it is missing the tag that you are search for. It should look like `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/YOUR_TAG_HERE/?hl=en`. Sorry if you intentionally remove it from the url though.